# Visual exploration of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, plot, jupyter-notebook

I'm working a lot with pandas dataframes containing timeseries.  To analyse the data, I make plots for a set of columns and for a slice in the (datetime) index.

However, I miss an interactive plot tool or gui that would allow me to:

- click in a list of columns which ones are to be plotted
- have a slider to scroll through time
- have a slider to set the length of the shown interval
- have mouse-over info with the values
- to compare timeseries with different scaling: either multiple y-axis in same plot or subplots (connected in time-domain)

Does anyone know a tool that has this functionality? Ideally this would be integrated in an ipython notebook, but a separate tool (taking a dataframe as input) would do.

Thanks!

Comment: sorry but asking for tools/resource recommendations is off-topic on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [charts](https://github.com/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts) library. It uses the interactive [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) javascript library to quickly create interactive plots. It has some cool features:

- Interactive charts (zoom, slide, hover over points, ...)
- Usable in an IPython notebook
- Directly plot pandas dataframes
- Use an interactive variable selector to select which variables you want to see. (This could be useful for you to plot your dataframe in one try and quickly scan the contents by adding and removing data)
- Plot any size of data using the asynchronous plot method
- Vector plots which you can download in .png, .jpg and .svg formats so you will never run into resolution problems.
- An interactive settings pane where you can change the settings of your chart after it has been plotted (!)

You can try it out [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts/blob/master/Tutorial.ipynb).

This could provide an easy alternative to bokeh when you are looking for a solution which is able to quickly scan the content in a dataframe.

*Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the charts library*

Comment: wow, this rocks.  Any possibility to add multiple axes or subplots (for differently scaled data)?

Comment: Multiple axes should be possible as is explained here: (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes/grid). However subplots are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to [Bokeh](http://bokeh.org), which does pretty much what you want from the gallery.

I haven't used it, so I don't know how "easy" it is to use it.

Interesting examples:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html#server-app-examples

It's not specific to pandas object though